# Can I send a POST form in an encoding other than of its body?

Tags: java, jsp, web-applications, encoding, servlets

I have an HTML page that looks like:

```
<HTML>
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=gb2312'>
<BODY onload='document.forms[0].submit();'>
<form name="form" method="post" action="/path/to/some/servlet">
<input type="hidden" name="username" value="麗安"> <!-- UTF-8 characters -->
</form>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

As you can see, the content of this page is UTF-8, but I need to send it with GB2312 character encoding, as the servlet that I am sending this page to expects from me GB2312.

Is this a valid scenario? Because in the servlet, I couldn't retrieve these Chinese characters back using a filter that sets the character encoding to GB2312!

I've created a sample Servlet:

```
package org.daz;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class EncodingServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final String ENCODING = "GB2312";

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
        throws ServletException, IOException {

        setCharacterEncoding(request, response);

        String username = request.getParameter("username");
        System.out.println(username);

    }

    private void setCharacterEncoding(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)throws IOException{
        request.setCharacterEncoding(ENCODING);
        response.setCharacterEncoding(ENCODING);
    }

}
```

The output is: `楹��`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. You'll need to use GB2312 characters from the beginning on instead, or to change the entire application to use UTF-8 only. You can't convert from character encoding X to character encoding Y that way. Any character outside the ASCII range would possibly get corrupted.

The form's `accept-charset` attribute as some suggest is ignored by most webbrowsers. The [W3 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/forms.html#adef-accept-charset) also literally states *"User agents **may** interpret .. "*, not *"must"*. And even then, it would only be used to encode the *actual* user input, not the hidden fields as in your example. They are already encoded in the page's own encoding (in this case GB2312). In other words, those UTF-8 characters are *already* corrupted at the moment the page is been processed by the browser.

Comment: Thanks too much, I've commented this conclusion at my blog: http://m-hewedy.blogspot.com/2010/05/beware-your-text-editor-encodes-your.html

Comment: You're welcome. My nickame is by the way **BalusC**, not *BlueC* ;)

Comment: Oh, you may find [this article](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html) useful as well to get more insight in the world of characters and bytes.

Comment: Thanks too much. If you please, I've referenced your blog article in my blog post.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try to do this,

```
<form name="form" method="post" action="/path/to/some/servlet" charset="gb2312" accept-encoding="gb2312">
<input type="hidden" name="username" value="麗安"> <!-- UTF-8 characters -->
</form>
```

It might work on some browsers. However, browser is not required to support GB2312 so your mileage may vary.

Comment: I've tried on both Firefox and Chrome, and seems not working for me!

Comment: It also depends on OS. It works for me on IE6 on Chinese Windows XP.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <form accept-charset="gb2312"
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/forms.html#adef-accept-charset